# Debugging thread macro -> or ->> in Clojure

Tags: debugging, clojure

I want to understand how works the following code that is designed for the problem: "Given a sequence of integers, find a continuous subsequence which maximizes the sum of its elements"

```
defn max-subseq-sum [coll]
(->> (take-while seq (iterate rest coll)) ; tails (1)
   (mapcat #(reductions conj [] %)) ; inits   (2)
   (apply max-key #(reduce + %)))) ; max sum
```

so I'd like to see the output of forms  (1), (2) and others. I can set breakpoints in Cursive but yet I don't know how to get these values.
I have tried to define a locale variables, for example

```
(defn max-subseq-sum [coll]
 (->> (take-while seq (iterate rest coll)) ; tails
      (let [d #(reductions conj [] %)]
       d  ) ; inits
      (apply  max-key #(reduce + %)))
 )

(max-subseq-sum [-1, -2, 3, 5, 6, -2, -1, 4, -4, 2, -1])
```

But i still don't understand how to see d, for example

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Read ALL of https://clojure.org/guides/repl/introduction until you get to https://clojure.org/guides/repl/enhancing_your_repl_workflow#debugging-tools-and-techniques, you will find all the techniques you need to get this kind of information and a lot more!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a nice library called [debux](https://github.com/philoskim/debux#debugging-thread-macro-code-code-or-code-code)

```
(use '[debux.core])

(defn max-subseq-sum [coll]
    (dbg (->> (take-while seq (iterate rest coll))                 ; tails (1)
          (mapcat #(reductions conj [] %))                        ; inits   (2)
          (apply max-key #(reduce + %)))))

(max-subseq-sum [1 2 3])


dbg: (->> (take-while seq (iterate rest coll)) (mapcat (fn* [p1__1991#] (re ... =>
| (take-while seq (iterate rest coll)) =>
|   ([1 2 3] (2 3) (3))
| (mapcat (fn* [p1__1991#] (reductions conj [] p1__1991#))) =>
|   ([] [1] [1 2] [1 2 3] [] [2] [2 3] [] [3])
| (apply max-key (fn* [p1__1992#] (reduce + p1__1992#))) =>
|   [1 2 3]
```

Answer (score 11):

A simple function that prints and returns its input can be inserted into the chain:

```
(defn debug [x]
  (println x)
  x)

(defn max-subseq-sum [coll]
  (->> (take-while seq (iterate rest coll))
       (debug)
       (mapcat #(reductions conj [] %))
       (apply max-key #(reduce + %))))

(max-subseq-sum [-1, -2, 3, 5, 6, -2, -1, 4, -4, 2, -1])
([-1 -2 3 5 6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1] (-2 3 5 6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (3 5 6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (5 6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (-2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (-1 4 -4 2 -1) (4 -4 2 -1) (-4 2 -1) (2 -1) (-1))
=> [3 5 6 -2 -1 4]
```

Or, if you want better tracking and don't mind a bit of bulk, you can use a macro that includes the expression in the printout:

```
(defmacro debugM [expr]
  `(let [x# ~expr] ; Save the result of the expression so it isn't evaluated twice
     (println '~expr "\n\t" x#)
     x#))

(defn max-subseq-sum [coll]
  (->> (take-while seq (iterate rest coll))
       (debugM)
       (mapcat #(reductions conj [] %))
       (apply max-key #(reduce + %))))

(max-subseq-sum [-1, -2, 3, 5, 6, -2, -1, 4, -4, 2, -1])
(take-while seq (iterate rest coll)) 
     ([-1 -2 3 5 6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1] (-2 3 5 6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (3 5 6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (5 6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (6 -2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (-2 -1 4 -4 2 -1) (-1 4 -4 2 -1) (4 -4 2 -1) (-4 2 -1) (2 -1) (-1))
=> [3 5 6 -2 -1 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

---

I could do by injecting `((fn [x] (println x) x))`.

```clj
(->> [1 2 3 4 5]
     (filter even?)
     ((fn [x] (println x) x))
     first)
```

that shows

```
(2 4)
2
```